# how to Parameterizing sql sentence for grouping and filtering

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, parameters, grouping

how do i parameterizing my sql sentence so i can get it to both do filtering and a grouping cause right now i can get it to group and filtering but not on the same time as for `SelectedParam` value is null when i trying to filter my groups

this the error i getting when i trying to filtering my groups

> Exception thrown: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in System.Data.dll Additional information: The parameterized query '(@param1 nvarchar(4000))Select ps.Mærket AS Mærke, P.DataID, P.B' expects the parameter '@param1'

CS

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{    
    public SqlConnection conn;
    public SqlCommand cmd;
    string connStrings = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Sql"];
    string Data = @"Select   ps.Mærket AS Mærke, P.DataID, P.Billed, P.Model, P.Årgang, P.[Motor Type], P.Krydsmål, P.Centerhul, P.ET,P.Bolter, P.Dæk, P.Fælge ,PS.Krydsmålene from Data.Hjuldata P  inner join Data.Mærke PS on P.MærkeID = PS.MærkeID ORDER BY ps.Mærket";
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private string _selectedParam;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
     BindData()
     ICollectionView dataView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(hjuldata.ItemsSource);
            dataView.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("Mærke"));

    }
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }
    public string SelectedParam { get { return _selectedParam; } set { _selectedParam = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedParam"); if (_selectedParam == "ingen") { BindData(); } else { hjuldata.ItemsSource = FilterKategori().Tables[0].DefaultView; ; } } }
    private void BindData()
    {
        hjuldata.ItemsSource = kategori().Tables[0].DefaultView;

    }
    public DataSet kategori()
    {
        //SQL statement to fetch entries from Hjuldata
        DataSet dsdata = new DataSet();

        //Open SQL Connection
        using (conn = new SqlConnection(connStrings))
        {
            conn.Open();

            //Initialize command object
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Data, conn))
            {                
                SqlDataAdapter adapters = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

                //Fill the result set
                adapters.Fill(dsdata);
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
        return dsdata;
    }
    public DataSet FilterKategori()
    {

    string Data = @"Select ps.Mærket AS Mærke, P.DataID, P.Billed, P.Model, 
P.Årgang, P.[Motor Type], P.Krydsmål, P.Centerhul, P.ET,P.Bolter, 
P.Dæk, P.Fælge ,PS.Krydsmålene from Data.Hjuldata P  
inner join Data.Mærke PS on P.MærkeID = PS.MærkeID 
WHERE Krydsmål = @param1";

   //SQL statement to fetch entries from products
            DataSet dsdata = new DataSet();

            //Open SQL Connection
            using (conn = new SqlConnection(connStrings))
            {
                conn.Open();

                //Initialize command object
                using (SqlCommand cmds = new SqlCommand(Data, conn))
                {
                    cmds.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", SelectedParam);
                    SqlDataAdapter adapters = new SqlDataAdapter(cmds);
                    //Fill the result set
                    adapters.Fill(dsdata);
                     conn.Close();
               }

            }
            return dsdata;
        }
```

combobox for doing filtering

```
<ComboBox x:Name="Krydsmålbox" Foreground="#FF00FB0B" Background="#FF303030" 
FontSize="12" Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxTest2}"  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource cmbTemplate2}" Margin="7,5,7,1" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectedValuePath="Krydsmålene" SelectedValue = "{Binding SelectedParam, ElementName=win, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
</ComboBox>
```

listview

```
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
  <Setter Property="Template">
   <Setter.Value>
   <ControlTemplate>
   <Expander IsExpanded="False"  BorderBrush="#FFEAEAEA" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" >
    <Expander.Header>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" DataContext="{Binding Items}">
    <Image Source="{Binding Billed}" Width="20" Height="20" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Margin="0,0,15,0"/>
     <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Mærke}" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#FFEAEAEA" FontSize="22" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Krydsmålet}"  FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#FFFBFB00" FontSize="22" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,150,0" TextAlignment="Center" />
      </StackPanel>
      </Expander.Header>
       <ItemsPresenter />
       </Expander>
       </ControlTemplate>
       </Setter.Value>
       </Setter>
       </Style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured out the issue was in

```
public string SelectedParam { get { return _selectedParam; } 
set { _selectedParam = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedParam");
if (_selectedParam == "ingen") { BindData(); } 
else { hjuldata.ItemsSource = FilterKategori().Tables[0].DefaultView; ; } } } 
private void BindData() { hjuldata.ItemsSource = kategori().Tables[0].DefaultView; };`
```

if i swapped around `hjuldata.ItemsSource = kategori().Tables[0].DefaultView`

with `hjuldata.ItemsSource = FilterKategori().Tables[0].DefaultView;` then it worked

but still the grouping doesn't

Answer (score 1):

Maybe create a stored procedure with an optional parameters, something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_getData
  @param1  NVARCHAR(1000) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @Sql Nvarchar(MAX);  

    SET @Sql = N'Select ps.Mærket AS Mærke
             , P.DataID
             , P.Billed
             , P.Model
             , P.Årgang
             , P.[Motor Type]
             , P.Krydsmål
             , P.Centerhul
             , P.ET
             ,P.Bolter
             ,P.Dæk
             , P.Fælge 
             ,PS.Krydsmålene 
        from Data.Hjuldata P  
        inner join Data.Mærke PS on P.MærkeID = PS.MærkeID 
        WHERE 1 = 1 '
        + CASE WHEN @param1 IS NOT NULL 
         THEN N' AND Krydsmål = @param1 ' ELSE N'' END

  Exec sp_executesql @Sql 
                    ,N'@param1  NVARCHAR(1000)'
                    ,@param1 

END
```

If you pass a value for `@Param1` only then the filter is applied else query is executed without the where clause, also the `@param1` parameter is optional with default value of `null`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use two sql. If param1 is not null, use one with where condition. If is null, use the other sql that doesn't have a where condition clause.